# Replace single quotes with double quotes in Postman

Tags: postman

I made a request in Postman and it runs like a charm. I export it as a code:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://release.local/api/v1/actions/execute' ^
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' ^
--header 'Accept: application/json' ^
--header 'X-Access-Token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTExLTA1VDEyOjMyOjExLjY3NjU4NVoiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiaXAiOiIxNzIuMTYuMC41MyIsInV1aWQiOiJjYTY3ZmU2NS1hZTU5LTQxMGEtYWNmYy1mNTZiOWRmN2ZiMWMiLCJmaW5nZXJwcmludCI6Ik1tUXpPV1kyWTJVelpHVTVNamhpWXc9PSJ9.OHiQ35RhLM2XRSFmI3uzvb4STHKTvgWx08cbiyRWhoM' ^
--data-raw '{
"context": "50b201df-862b-4d93-930c-dc6480db4c4e",
"action_id": "191a7123-bcda-44ee-b615-80c09b4b3091",
"payload": []
}'
```

But single quotes do not work with Win10 curl. Is it possible to configure Postman to replace them with double quotes?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5308#issuecomment-503249780, but I cannot find the "Experimental Codegen Mode" in the Postman settings.